# Pass variable from class to activity

Tags: android, variables, global

I am really struggling with this one
I have an activity called demo.java
This is my main activity. inside this it calls another class to display a large bitmap by subsampling like this

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

this goes to the class SubsamplingScaleImageView.java
It displays the bitmap and has a double tap event

When the screen is double tapped it runs the following

```
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent ev) {

            int x = (int)ev.getX();
            int y = (int)ev.getY();

            SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            PointF sCoord = imageView.viewToSourceCoord(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            if(sCoord.x > 1940 && sCoord.x < 2119 && sCoord.y > 1558 && sCoord.y < 1719){  roomname="141";   };
            return true;
        }
```

It sets the variable "roomname" to "141"

then returns to the main demo.java

I need to be able to use roomname in that class but it is not there
I have tried searching for examples of global varibles but I just cant work it out

Any help is appreciated

Mark

Comment: Explain better what is the `class` and what is the `activity`

Comment: Is what you mean by `class` an `Activity`? If your demo `Activity` is starting another activity where `roomname` is set, you need to send this back as a result. Look into the `startActivityForResult()` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be making roomname a `public static` variable of a class (i.e. class Demo), which you could then access nearly anywhere via Demo.roomname. This is generally considered bad practice, but should be sufficient.

```
class Demo {
    public static string roomname;
}
```

and then to access it:

```
Demo.roomname
```